# Import from .csv to sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, csv

I am using sqlite to create a Database with table which has to be just like the csv file along with the headers and data.

what is the best way to create a table in the sqlite database with schema and data from the .csv file.

can i avoid writing the script for the CREATE table?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I've used SQL Server Import and Export Wizard in the past for creating simple tables from a file. It can automatically detect data types and create the table.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Comment: I have to use a compact DB and I am looking for some way to get one from the csv

Comment: Apologies, though it would work for you-- I wonder if you can grab the CREATE command from the wizard and use on your own